# iPad low memory warning, although no other apps are running, and my app allocates only 8 MB

Tags: ios, didreceivememorywarning

I am receiving low memory warnings on the iPad (inspected via instruments) although no other apps are running, and my app has only 8 MB of live bytes.

In my understanding, iOS triggers memory warnings only, if the system is running out of resources. How can it be, that I still get them?

(To get a better understanding of the issue and the related circumstances, please check this question: [Empty drawRect implementation causes memory warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028099/empty-drawrect-implementation-causes-memory-warning))

Comment: Maybe you have a memory leak ?

Comment: No leaks. Well almost no leaks (a couple of KBs). Do I get low memory warnings from iOS if my app has leaks? Even if there were enough free memory?

Comment: trying to take a picture maybe? This can happen if you try to take a picture for example, as that data is stored in the RAM memory and you either need to save it on the disk or pass it along.

Comment: No. Just edited the question anyway for a better understanding.

Comment: What're you doing while the app go low memory? I mean what kind of task

Comment: Zooming into a view which shows a UIBezierPath: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028099/empty-drawrect-implementation-causes-memory-warning

Comment: Did u manage to solve this? I run into the same issue..

Comment: This was a long time ago. I did not find a solution per se. All I remember is that I used a whole different approach with a whole new code.