# iOS and Cocos2d: received low memory warning with only 20 MB of allocation and no ther app running

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone, low-memory

I am getting low memory warnings even if my App is allocating only 20 MB of memory and there are apparently no leaks (See photo below). I am wondering whether this is due to some iOS version I am using (deployment target iOS 5.0 and running on an iPod touch 4th gen Version 5.0.1 (9A405)).

[image: low memory warning]

In the simulator this doesn't seem to appear.

Any suggestion?

EDIT: [This is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028427/ipad-low-memory-warning-although-no-other-apps-are-running-and-my-app-allocate) I found but not using Cocos2D. There is no answer to that quesiton to date.

Comment: It would be important to know what kind of device you are running it on?

Comment: Its written in the question " iPod touch 4th gen Version 5.0.1 (9A405)", bought last year.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshots its clear that the allocations spike noticably, I would say by a factor of 5 or more. That means for a short time your app is using 100+ MB of memory while most of the time it may only be using 20 MB.

Click on the time graph above one of the spikes to see what the memory usage at that point was, and which objects were using the most memory. Memory warnings can occur a bit later than the spikes so don't rely on their exact timing, but you can see that the alerts happened shortly after a memory usage spike.

[Read this article](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/11/optimize-memory-usage-bundle-size-cocos2d-app/) to learn a few tricks to decrease memory usage spikes. Specifically loading the textures in the order from largest to smallest helps, as does using the .pvr.ccz image file format. Avoid using JPG images, they add a lot of memory overhead when loading (and because of that also load a lot slower than the other formats).

Comment: Also, 100mb is huge on devices with average 512 mb RAM.

Comment: not really, it would be difficult to run such an app stable on 256 mb devices